# The correct way to rename a QTreeView item?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I am trying to Rename items in a QTreeView (based on QFileSystemModel). Basically when you click something in the QTreeView then click the button "change name", the item's name is changed.

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def change_name(clicked, name):
        """NEED HELP HERE.
        """
        pass

    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance()

    widget = QWidget()

    ROOT = "D:/"

    treeModel = QFileSystemModel()
    treeModel.setRootPath(ROOT)

    treeView = QTreeView()
    treeView.setModel(treeModel)
    treeView.setRootIndex(treeModel.index(ROOT))
    treeView.setColumnHidden(1,True)
    treeView.setColumnHidden(2,True) 
    treeView.setColumnHidden(3,True) 

    btn = QPushButton("change to ABC")
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda clicked: change_name(clicked, "ABC"))
    btn2 = QPushButton("change to XXX")
    btn2.clicked.connect(lambda clicked: change_name(clicked, "XXX"))

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(treeView)
    layout.addWidget(btn)
    layout.addWidget(btn2)

    widget.setLayout(layout)
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please, **do not** edit the question to ask something else. Create a new post!

Comment: But this problem has not been completely solved...

Comment: It *is* solved in the strict sense of the question, and, in any case, you must **not** edit a question by *changing* the code based on an answer, as it makes it confusing and incoherent. You should remember that StackOverflow is a Q&A website *for everyone*: meaning that people should be able to find solutions to their problems by finding an existing question similar to their needs. If somebody else finds your answer, they won't understand what's wrong with it, since you've modified it. If you have an issue with a specific answer, use comments in **that** answer, otherwise create a new post.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in your other question, you must first ensure that the model is writable by using [`setReadOnly(False)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#readOnly-prop), then renaming can be done through [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setData) or directly from the view (which does the same thing).

Also, your function doesn't make a lot of sense: the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) signal has a `bool` argument, which is clearly useless for what you need.

If you dont' want to allow renaming from the view, you either change the readOnly property on the fly (possibly by checking that the previous state is correctly restored), or you disable editing by using [`setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#editTriggers-prop).

Finally, if you want to change the name of the *current* index (the selected file) programmatically, you have to get it from the view.

```
    def change_name(name):
        index = treeView.currentIndex()
        if index.isValid():
            wasReadOnly = treeModel.isReadOnly()
            treeModel.setReadOnly(False)
            treeModel.setData(index, name)
            treeModel.setReadOnly(wasReadOnly)

    # ...
    btn = QPushButton("change to ABC")
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda: change_name("ABC"))
    btn2 = QPushButton("change to XXX")
    btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: change_name("XXX"))
    # ...
```

Comment: Why should treeModel be set to the previous state and not simply setReadOnly(True)?

Comment: The first args of the slot function is used to receive the signal. Why shouldn't it be "def change_name(clicked, name):"?

Comment: @g2m.agent 1) because there might be reasons for which you need to change the state elsewhere (for instance, you want to enable renaming from the view), so it's good practice to restore it in such situations; if you're sure that you won't do that, just set it when you create the instance; 2) (see the update) the clicked signal is useless, so you shouldn't use it in the lambda.

Comment: How did you get a gray background to the message?

Comment: What gray background on what message?

Comment: If I have a QItemSelectionModel, something like treeSelection=treeView.selectionModel() . which is better, treeSelection.currentIndex() or treeView.currentIndex() ?

Comment: They are the same thing, as the `currentIndex()` of the view actually returns the `currentIndex()` of its selection model. Using the view's current index is usually better, as it ensures that the current selection model is always used.

Comment: Hello, I found a bug, I have encountered it before. Please help me see if you have time, thank you. see above.